# how I install a batch script in windows startup?

Tags: batch-processing

I have a batch script which upload and download only new files. I converted the script from .bat to .exe, my question:

I don't want to press the .exe every time i want to excute the program, i want to install the .exe like a software in windows and even after booting it will still do the job, like adding it to startup or registry.

How I can install my exe using batch script into windows?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a batch script. You can place a shortcut (w/params) in the Windows "Startup" folder. See http://www.ehow.com/how_6148318_change-windows-startup-folder.html on how to find and place stuff in your startup folder.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for the link, I have to do uploading and downloading files through ftp on all computers in LAN, I thought there is a away to make my scripts get installed automatically like any software and start automatically after booting.

Comment: Which version of windows? And if the exe is running continously, it may be best to use a service. Have a look here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758918%28WS.10%29.aspx